# Where clause removing calculations from my query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am having a trying to calculate a result set for myself but I am facing a strange problem where the **WHERE** clause is creating problems for me.

The table are as follows:-

```
Customer
CustomerId CustomerName
2          Jayesh
5          Hasan

SaleInvoiceMaster
CustomerId TotalInvoiceAmount
1          50000

PurchaseInvoiceMaster
CustomerId TotalInvoiceAmount
1          10000

PaymentTransactions 
CustomerId PaymentAmount
1          10000
```

The result set that is working is as follows:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerId AS CustomerId, C.Name AS CustomerName, ISNULL(SIM.TotalSale, 0), ISNULL(PIM.TotalPurchase, 0), ISNULL(PT.TotalPaid, 0), ISNULL(SIM.TotalSale - PIM.TotalPurchase - PT.TotalPaid, 0) AS AmountPending
FROM Customers AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CustomerId, ISNULL(SUM(TotalInvoiceAmount),0) AS TotalSale FROM SaleInvoiceMaster GROUP BY CustomerId) AS SIM ON SIM.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CustomerId, ISNULL(SUM(TotalInvoiceAmount),0) AS TotalPurchase FROM PurchaseInvoiceMaster GROUP BY CustomerId) AS PIM ON PIM.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CustomerId, PaymentStatus, ISNULL(SUM(PaymentAmount),0) AS TotalPaid FROM PaymentTransactions AS P GROUP BY CustomerId, PaymentStatus) AS PT ON PT.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
```

The result for the same is as shown in below image

[Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5BjI.png)

When I add a where clause at the end f the third left outer join, the problem arises. The calculation stops and it shows zero. My updated query is as follows:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerId AS CustomerId, C.Name AS CustomerName, ISNULL(SIM.TotalSale, 0), ISNULL(PIM.TotalPurchase, 0), ISNULL(PT.TotalPaid, 0), ISNULL(SIM.TotalSale - PIM.TotalPurchase - PT.TotalPaid, 0) AS AmountPending
FROM Customers AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CustomerId, ISNULL(SUM(TotalInvoiceAmount),0) AS TotalSale FROM SaleInvoiceMaster GROUP BY CustomerId) AS SIM ON SIM.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CustomerId, ISNULL(SUM(TotalInvoiceAmount),0) AS TotalPurchase FROM PurchaseInvoiceMaster GROUP BY CustomerId) AS PIM ON PIM.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CustomerId, ISNULL(SUM(PaymentAmount),0) AS TotalPaid FROM PaymentTransactions AS PT1 WHERE (PT1.PaymentStatus = 'Payment Made' OR PT1.PaymentStatus = 'Bad Debt') GROUP BY CustomerId) AS PT ON PT.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
```

The result set becomes:-

[Result denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCLtk.png)

Comment: Where is this column `PaymentStatus`? I can see it in your filter, but no where else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN your main select body you are doing this:

```
ISNULL(SIM.TotalSale - PIM.TotalPurchase - PT.TotalPaid, 0) AS AmountPending
```

This is returning 0 if ANY of those columns are NULL, you want this instead:

```
ISNULL(SIM.TotalSale, 0) - ISNULL(PIM.TotalPurchase, 0) - ISNULL(PT.TotalPaid, 0) AS AmountPending
```

Or for more current syntax, use COALESCE instead of ISNULL:

```
COALESCE(SIM.TotalSale, 0) - COALESCE(PIM.TotalPurchase, 0) - COALESCE(PT.TotalPaid, 0) AS AmountPending
```

Answer (score 0):

You are have several confusions in the query.  First, you don't need `select distinct` in the outermost query.  Second, there is a difference between a subquery returning no matching rows and a `NULL` value in the subquery.  Third, you are adding potentially `NULL` values together.

An improved version of the query:

```
SELECT C.CustomerId, C.Name AS CustomerName,
       COALESCE(SIM.TotalSale, 0) as TotalSale, 
       COALESCE(PIM.TotalPurchase, 0) as TotalPurchase, 
       COALESCE(PT.TotalPaid, 0) as TotalPaid,
       (COALESCE(SIM.TotalSale, 0) - COALESCE(PIM.TotalPurchase, 0) 
 - COALESCE(PT.TotalPaid, 0)
       ) as AmountPending
FROM Customers C LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT CustomerId, SUM(TotalInvoiceAmount) AS TotalSale
      FROM SaleInvoiceMaster
      GROUP BY CustomerId
     ) SIM
     ON SIM.CustomerId = C.CustomerId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT CustomerId, SUM(TotalInvoiceAmount) AS TotalPurchase
      FROM PurchaseInvoiceMaster
      GROUP BY CustomerId
     ) PIM
     ON PIM.CustomerId = C.CustomerId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT CustomerId, SUM(PaymentAmount) AS TotalPaid
      FROM PaymentTransactions PT1
      WHERE PT1.PaymentStatus IN ('Payment Made', 'Bad Debt')
      GROUP BY CustomerId
     ) PT
     ON PT.CustomerId = C.CustomerId;
```

Removing the `SELECT DISTINCT` improves performance and makes the query more readable.  Assuming `CustomerId` is unique in `Customers`, duplicates cannot be created.

Removing the `ISNULL()` in the subqueries makes the query more readable.  This operation does nothing, because the `NULL`s need to be handled *after* the `JOIN`.

Replacing the `OR` with `IN` make the query more readable.